# post data to a site and load it in another site in iframe (angular and c#)

Tags: javascript, c#, angular, iframe

I have two different angular 5 projects(siteone & sitetwo). 
sitetwo is dashboard and i have to load that inside an iframe in siteone, on click of a tab "dashboard". 
But, a form that will have certain inputs should be submitted first to sitetwo url and then its loaded in iframe.

my iframe component looks like myiframe.html

```
<div *ngIf="strurl">
    <object data="">
        <embed height="1200"  width="100%" [src]="strurl">
    </object> 
</div>
```

where strurl comes from service call and i have used domsanitizer to avoid safeurl issue, i have to use same url in iframe. I have used router.navigate to load respective components on click of tabs.

kindly suggest a solution for how to post data to site2 then load it in iframe in site1.

(please note:- this a short time solution untill we are adopting plugin architecture for inter application uses)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Safe Pipe:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer} from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Pipe({ name: 'safe' })
export class SafePipe implements PipeTransform {
   constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}
   transform(url) {
     return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(url);
   }
}
```

HTML Code:

```
<embed height="1200"  width="100%" [src]="strurl | safe"">
```

Comment: sorry if my question was not very clear. ill update my problem statement. my problem is how to post data from site1 to site2 and load it in iframe.